# How to transfer Userpoints between users?

Tags: 7, userpoints

I installed the [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module (v7.x-1.0) and after going through all of the configuration I cannot seem to find the option for transferring Points between users.

Can someone point out how I find/activate this feature?

Comment: Is that listed as a feature of the module somewhere (it's not one that I'm aware of and there's nothing that suggests it has that functionality on the module page)? If not then this is a feature request which needs to go in the module issue queue...

Comment: I thought I'd read somewhere that the feature was a part of the module. Now looking back over the module page it doesn't appear to be a feature. Does anyone know if a module exists that adds this function? All I can find is this code (http://drupaldeveloper.in/codelet/drupal-donate-userpoints-node-author) which allows them to be donated.

Comment: Check this: https://drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib
Its still under development!

Comment: Thanks. The 'userpoints_donation' module that is contained within that collection of contributed modules is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Module Userpoints Donation has to be used.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 approaches you can choose from, as further detailed below.

## User points donations

Use the [Userpoints Donation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/userpoints_contrib/tree/userpoints_donation?h=7.x-1.x) module, which is a submodule included in the (D7 version of the) [Userpoints Contrib](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib) module.

If you use/enable it, make sure to also grant the required permission related to it (and to avoid asking yourself "[How is the module Userpoints Donation intended to work?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181891/how-is-the-module-userpoints-donation-intended-to-work/206547#206547)" ...).

## Rules

Use the integration between the [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module and the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to "roll your own cookies", by writing some custom rules to transfer user points from one account to another. As a sample, have a look at this rule, which is used in combination with voting of a node, whereas the author looses "-2" points, and the voter looses "-1" points:

```
{ "rules_votedown_question" : {
    "LABEL" : "votedown_question",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "answers" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "voting_rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "voting_rules_insert_node" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : {
          "node" : [ "node" ],
          "type" : { "value" : { "answers_question" : "answers_question" } }
        }
      },
      { "voting_rules_condition_check_vote_value" : { "vote" : [ "vote" ], "value" : "-1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "node:author" ],
          "points" : "-2",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Receive downvote to [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionDownvoteReceived",
          "reference" : "By uid=[vote:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      },
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "vote:user" ],
          "points" : "-1",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Issue downvote to [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionDownvoteIssued",
          "reference" : "From uid=[node:author:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you simply adapt the amount of points (-2 and -1) to something like (eg) +25 and -25, you've a prototype to transfer (25) user points from one user to another. If you replace the Rules event by an event like "something is flagged" (created with the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module), a simple click could be used to indicate "I want to transfer 25 user points of mine to this user).