# How is the module Userpoints Donation intended to work?

Tags: 7, userpoints

I enabled the Userpoints Donation module (part of [Userpoints Contrib](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib)). Then I put a check in the settings for the type of material - (Choose which content types should show a donate points link).

What's next? Nothing has changed. It says "Only the checked content types will show a donate points link". But no reference appeared.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the Userpoints Donation module is mentioned [near the top of the module's source](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/userpoints_contrib/tree/userpoints_donation/userpoints_donation.module?h=7.x-1.x#n3):

> ... uses [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) API to give users ability to give points to users.

But "*give*" actually means "*transfer*", as shown in [`userpoints_donation_giveform_submit()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/userpoints_contrib/tree/userpoints_donation/userpoints_donation.module?h=7.x-1.x#n210), which:

- increments the amount of points for the user who receives the donation (= **receiver**).
- reduces the same amount of points for the user who donates them(= **donator**).

Before actually doing so, various [extra validations](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/userpoints_contrib/tree/userpoints_donation/userpoints_donation.module?h=7.x-1.x#n165) are performed, such as:

- Does the donator have sufficient points, so that after transferring the points the user points balance of the donator is still positive?).
- The receiver has to be a valid user.
- You cannot transfer points to yourself.
- The amount of points donated cannot be below 1 user point (which also implies that the donator can only "*give*" points, not "*take*" points ...).
- ...

However, for an appropriate link (with title "*Donate points to this user*") to be shown to the user who wants to do such donation, it is required that such user has been granted the permission "***give points to another user***". So if "*Nothing has changed*" (as in your question), it could well be that the required permission has not been granted yet.